# Golang:How to Feed Query Result Slice into Struct Feild?

Tags: go

I've been attempting to feed my SQL query result into my Struct that is displaying in my react front end however my db.select() only outputs into slices and i'm uncertain how to get my results into the Sum Field in my struct.

The results display fine in my VScode console as shown below.

[{1382     } {1367     } {1342     } {662     } {1863     } {1977     } {2269     }]

However i cant find any method to feed my Result variable into my Structs Sum feild.

My code is below any help would be great!

```
type Tag struct { Sum string json:"sum" Query_desc string json:"Query_Desc" Query_start_date string json:"Query_start_date" Query_end_date string json:"Query_end_date" Current_date string json:"Current_date" Error_info string json:"Error_Info" }

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r http.Request) { w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "") w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")

db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "****")

date_1 := r.FormValue("date_1") 
date_2 := r.FormValue("date_2")

var tag Tag

result := []Tag{}

Query := ("SELECT ROUND(SUM(duration)/3600,0) sum FROM sessions WHERE (app_id = 'idrice' OR app_id ='idrios' OR app_id ='' OR **** =''OR app_id ='') AND date(created ) between ? and ? and time(created ) between '16:00:00' and '18:00:00' AND (media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR ****='' OR ****='****') GROUP BY date(created)")

err = db.Select(&result, Query, date_1, date_2)

tag.Query_desc = "Listener Hours" 
tag.Query_start_date = date_1 
tag.Query_end_date = date_2 dt := time.Now() 
tag.Current_date = dt.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05") 

if err != nil { tag.Error_info = err.Error() }

j, err := json.Marshal(tag) if err != nil { w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest) w.Write([]byte((err.Error()))) return } w.Write(j)

}

func main() { http.HandleFunc("/", handler) log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)) }
```

Comment: The output seems to be what you say you want. What is it that you do not like about `[{1382 }...]`?

Comment: The output is fine i'm just trying to pass it into the Sum Field in my tag struct

Comment: Loop over `result`, convert each individual element's `Sum` field to an `int` and add the some pre-declared `int` variable that will hold the aggregate, once the loop's done you can convert that pre-declared variable to a string and assign that to `tag.Sum`.

Comment: How would i do this? Apologies i'm New to Golang

Comment: You can do it with a `for` loop and the `strconv` package. Go's official page has lots of information on loops. And `pkg.go.dev` has documentation on Go's standard lib.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

type Tag struct {
    Sum              string `json:"sum"`
    Query_desc       string `json:"query_desc"`
    Query_start_date string `json:"query_start_date"`
    Query_end_date   string `json:"query_end_date"`
    Current_date     string `json:"current_date"`
    Error_info       string `json:"error_info"`
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")

    db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "****")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    date_1 := r.FormValue("date_1")
    date_2 := r.FormValue("date_2")

    var tag Tag

    result := []Tag{}

    Query := ("SELECT ROUND(SUM(duration)/3600,0) sum FROM sessions WHERE (app_id = 'idrice' OR app_id ='idrios' OR app_id ='' OR **** =''OR app_id ='') AND date(created ) between ? and ? and time(created ) between '16:00:00' and '18:00:00' AND (media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR ****='' OR ****='****') GROUP BY date(created)")

    err = db.Select(&result, Query, date_1, date_2)

    tag.Query_desc = "Listener Hours"
    tag.Query_start_date = date_1
    tag.Query_end_date = date_2
    dt := time.Now()
    tag.Current_date = dt.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05")

    // define a aggregateSum variable to hold the sum of all the values in the result set

    var aggregateSum int
    // loop through the result set and add the values to the aggregateSum variable
    for _, v := range result {
        d, err := strconv.Atoi(v.Sum) // convert the string value to an integer
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        aggregateSum += d
    }

    tag.Sum = strconv.Itoa(aggregateSum) // convert the integer to a string and assign it to the Sum field of the tag struct


    if err != nil {
        tag.Error_info = err.Error()
    }

    j, err := json.Marshal(tag)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte((err.Error())))
        return
    }
    w.Write(j)

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```